# Посоветуйте PDF конвертер

Tags: delphi, pdf

Использую Delphi XE8. Надо мержить и вставлять в документ ссылки на файлы. файлов для слияния много. Использовал `pdftk` и `cpdf`. если я пытаюсь вставить в виде ссылки путь к файлу в котором есть папки с русскими буками, то начинаются проблемы. Пробовал `PDFtoolkit VCL` от `Gnostice` но у него утечки. Посоветуйте для этих целей нормальный конвертер

Answer (score 1):

Я не так давно писал конвертер для чеков, чтобы в pdf хранились. Использовал http://synopse.info/fossil/wiki?name=PDF+Engine
Но надо учесть, что у меня RAD Studio XE3, а под XE8 - не могу сказать, заработает ли сразу, но код открытый.
Уверен, что можно задаться целью и прикрутить, как тебе надо. Успехов !

Comment: Позволяет ли Synopse работать с готовыми PDF? Насколько я знаю - нет. Мне нужно производить слияние файлов в один.

Comment: Если они без защиты - должны и мержиться, и даже конвертиться. Я чеки сливал в один. Надо доки копать.

Comment: Если не принципиально можно слияние через внешние онлайн-сервисы делать - благо их сейчас достаточно. Отправил на туда, выполнил слияние, download и готово. Как вариант )

Comment: Вы можете привести пример по объединению нескольких файлов используя эту библиотеку?

Comment: Не сразу. Но посмотрю, если найду те исходники - кину код.

Comment: [ссылка](http://www.trichview.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=6010)
Вот здесь, таким способом (если поочередно через TRichMemo приклеивать) должны лепиться в один документ. Своих исходников не надыбал пока, но я тоже пользовался подобным методом. Открываешь один новый pdf, и в него через LoadFromFile в какое-нибудь Memo постранично cклеиваешь. Ну и потом SaveToFile, разумеется.